# Use Spring boot embedded tomcat connection pool without jdbctemplate, hibernate or JPA

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot, connection-pooling

I'm integrating Spring boot to replace existing RESTful API we already had. I want to use the connection pool which comes with it. I'm new to Spring boot. I see in `DataSource` object that I can get connection but it is returning `null`.

I also know that it's not a best practice to try to use this connection outside separately.

How can I use a Spring boot JDBC connection with my existing Core java Database Access Object?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you mean `dataSource.getConnection()` returns null or is your datasource null? If you don't want to use spring jdbc, hibernate etc then obviously you can use standard driver datasource or any other pooled datasource i.e. apache-dbcp for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean in configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
      ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(connectURI,null);
      PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
      ObjectPool objectPool = new GenericObjectPool(poolableConnectionFactory);
      PoolingDataSource dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(objectPool);
      return dataSource;
    }
```